# r - Last match of regular expression

Tags: regex, r, taxonomy, gsub

I am looking for an `R` pattern matching expression that extracts the last  fully populated taxonomy in each element in the list. The taxonomies have always the same format (one letter two underscores and a word (some times inside square brackets). Taxonomies that are not fully populated they don't have the word after the two underscores.

I was able to build a expression that worked in one regular expression builder website
 `(.\_\_[A-Za-z\[\]]+)(?!.*__[A-Za-z\[\])` 
but had not luck using it or transforming it to use an `R` pattern matching methods in `grep {base}` or anything similar. Here is one of the things I tried

```
clean=gsub("(.\_\_[A-Za-z[]]+)(?!.*__[A-Za-z[]])","\\1",taxonomies,perl = TRUE)
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

```
taxonomies=
  list('k__Bacteria; p__Bacteroidetes; c__[Saprospirae]; o__[Saprospirales]; f__Chitinophagaceae; g__; s__'
       ,'k__Bacteria; p__Actinobacteria; c__MB-A2-108; o__0319-7L14; f__; g__; s__'
       ,'k__Bacteria; p__Actinobacteria; c__Actinobacteria; o__Actinomycetales;f__Corynebacteriaceae; g__Corynebacterium; s__'
       ,'k__Bacteria; p__Proteobacteria; c__Betaproteobacteria; o__Rhodocyclales; f__Rhodocyclaceae; g__Methyloversatilis; s__'
       ,'k__Bacteria; p__Proteobacteria; c__Deltaproteobacteria; o__Myxococcales; f__; g__; s__'
       ,'k__Bacteria; p__Proteobacteria; c__[Deltaproteobacteria]; o__[W123]; f__[W123]; g__[W123]; s__[W123.012.123]'
       ,'k__Bacteria; p__Bacteroidetes; c__[Saprospirae]; o__[Saprospirales]; f__Chitinophagaceae')
```

Desired output

```
[1] "f__Chitinophagaceae"  "o__0319-7L14" "g__Corynebacterium"   
[4] "g__Methyloversatilis" "o__Myxococcales"  "s__[W123.012.123]"   
[7] "f__Chitinophagaceae"
```

**Edit**
Included desired output, example code gsub that is not working.

Comment: Consider showing the result you want.

Comment: I second the advice from @mark-miller and hope to help by asking: Did you add `perl=TRUE` as parameter to the regex as to enable the PCRE library (often the *dialect* of such a meta language is the problem where we get stuck)? Oh and maybe show `R` code that produces an unwanted result you tried? That would help us to help you I think. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Dilettant and @Mark-Miller, I edited the question for clarity of future users. It seems, however,  that akrun below was able to solve my problem already.

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(unlist(taxonomies), ';'), function(i) tail(i[nchar(i)>4], 1))` should work

Comment: Yes @Sotos, this code works too. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `stri_extract_last` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_last(unlist(taxonomies), regex = '[A-Za-z]__\\[*[[:alnum:].-]+\\]*')
#[1] "f__Chitinophagaceae"  "o__0319-7L14" "g__Corynebacterium"   
#[4] "g__Methyloversatilis" "o__Myxococcales"  "s__[W123.012.123]"   
#[7] "f__Chitinophagaceae"
```

Here, I assumed that the OP meant to extract the characters within `**...**`.  It must be some formatting issue as it was not shown in **BOLD**.

#### data

```
taxonomies=list(
  'k__Bacteria; p__Bacteroidetes; c__[Saprospirae]; o__[Saprospirales]; f__Chitinophagaceae; g__; s__'
  ,'k__Bacteria; p__Actinobacteria; c__MB-A2-108; o__0319-7L14; f__; g__; s__'
  ,'k__Bacteria; p__Actinobacteria; c__Actinobacteria; o__Actinomycetales;f__Corynebacteriaceae; g__Corynebacterium; s__'
 ,'k__Bacteria; p__Proteobacteria; c__Betaproteobacteria; o__Rhodocyclales; f__Rhodocyclaceae; g__Methyloversatilis; s__'
 ,'k__Bacteria; p__Proteobacteria; c__Deltaproteobacteria; o__Myxococcales; f__; g__; s__'
  ,'k__Bacteria; p__Proteobacteria; c__[Deltaproteobacteria]; o__[W123]; f__[W123]; g__[W123]; s__[W123.012.123]'
  ,'k__Bacteria; p__Bacteroidetes; c__[Saprospirae]; o__[Saprospirales]; f__Chitinophagaceae'
  )
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what I needed. I realize using the **bold** text wasn't the best way to present my issue, but I am happy you were able to look past that. I edited the question so hopefully more people can understand and benefit.